# Web API .net core 2 request check the request's header is not empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, httpresponse

How can I verify whether the request's header some-header matches book's bookId?

```
    public IActionResult GetBooks()
    {
        // if 'some-header' value is empty, null , whitespace or request contains multiple ' some-header' headers then it should return UnauthorizedResult();
       // if 'some-header' is not above then it needs to be read from repository
    }
    public class Book 
    {
     public string bookId {get; set;}
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Request.Headers.GetValues()` will return an `IEnumerable<string>`  that correspond the headers from the HTTP request , then you can validate wether this contains multiple values or if its only one check if is null or white space ( which includes empty )

```
Request.Headers.TryGetValue("some-header", out var headers);         
if(headers.Count > 1 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers.FirstOrDefault())){
   return new UnauthorizedResult();
}
```

Comment: 'IHeaderDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'GetValues' and no accessible extension method 'GetValues' accepting a first argument of type 'IHeaderDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I am using .net core 2. do I have to add any specific reference?

Comment: @Lauren Apparently that did method did not exist I changed my code with the correct method

Comment: cannot convert from 'out System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'out Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues'

Comment: @Lauren Check my new edit , sorry for wasting a bit your time I should test things before post it in SO!

Comment: Should it be `return new UnauthorizedResult();`?